# How can I make custom waypoints on water with a click in mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a map on my website that just shows the map and the location of me(later this is going to change to the location of an little boat). I want to mark a path in the water so the boat can travel in that exact path, so for example from point A to B to C etc. but I couldn't figure out how to do that with dropbox. So basically an delivery route but then on water. can anyone help me! this is what I have so far:

this is my map.html

```
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map { position: absolute  ; top: 56px; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        #buttons { position: absolute; bottom: 0; margin: 0 0 10px 25px}
    </style>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body >

<div id="map"></div>

<div >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="buttons">asdasd</button>
</div>
</body>
<script src="../js/map.js">


</script>
</html>
```

and this is my map.js:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my_token';

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
    center: [-96, 37.8], // starting position
    zoom: 3 // starting zoom
});

const geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl()
map.addControl(geolocate)

map.on('load', function()
{
    geolocate.trigger();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to store at regular intervals the position of the boat (store it in a simple variable, write it in a file, use an API, use localStorage, everything depends on the use). Then you just have to add a layer of type "line" which will use the different points recorded to draw lines between each point.

[image]

Here is a working example https://codepen.io/cladjidane/pen/MWrJjjw

```
mapboxgl.accessToken =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoiY2xhZGppZGFuZSIsImEiOiJjbDA4NmVra3gwMG1jM2dvM3V1djh2NnFwIn0.m8Swm9zWKqf0ozaNcZtISQ'

// Init map
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', 
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', 
  center: [-122.02991,37.33265],
  zoom: 12,
})

// Definition of the configuration for GeolocateControl 
let geolocate = new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
  positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 15000,
    maximumAge: 0,
  },
  trackUserLocation: true,
});
map.addControl(geolocate)

// Once the map is loaded
map.on('load', function () {
  geolocate.trigger();

  // We create a data source - GeoJSON format
  const position_boat = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: [
      {
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {},
        geometry: {
          type: 'LineString',
          coordinates: [],
        },
      },
    ],
  }

  // We add to the map this source
  map.addSource('route', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: position_boat,
  })

  // All the magic happens here: 
  // We push in our source the table of coordinates updated with the method "geolocate". 
  geolocate.on('geolocate', function (position) {
    let newCoordinates = [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude]
    position_boat.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push(newCoordinates)
    map.getSource('route').setData(position_boat)
  })

  // We add the layer that displays the source on the map
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'route',
    type: 'line',
    source: 'route',
    layout: {
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round',
    },
    paint: {
      'line-color': 'red',
      'line-width': 8,
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: how could I test this? when I add some values in position, I'm not seing anything

Comment: I'm on mac and I use to test the safari browser of the simulator integrated in Xcode. The simulator allows you to simulate the movement of the device. But maybe there are other solutions in the form of a browser extension? https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-simulate-location-in-xcode-and-simulator/